# leaving time delay in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, delay

I have a form in which I need to give timedelay of 3 seconds before each line executes. But when I try system.threading.thread.sleep it's freezing the UI and furthermore all delays are executing as one single delay.
that is

if I have

```
label.text = "intializing..."
sleep(5000)
label1.text = "connectinh..."
sleep(5000)
label2.text = "connected..."
sleep(5000)
```

the UI freezes for 15 seconds totally and then all executiong happens instantaneously as if there was no delay statement between them. I was not able to find out anything else other than threading.sleep.

Comment: Saying "this is urgent" won't get you quicker answers. At best, people will just ignore it; at worst, it will irritate them and they'll stop reading...

Comment: its just an adjective, i dont know why ppl have to get irritated with it. I explained my problem clearly and said its urgent. I dont think theres nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Ron said:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, _
                        e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf showLabelText)
    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()
End Sub

Const delaySecs As Integer = 3

Private Sub showLabelText()
    Dim del As New foo(AddressOf updLabel)

    Label1.BeginInvoke(del, "one")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaySecs * 1000)

    Label1.BeginInvoke(del, "two")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaySecs * 1000)

    Label1.BeginInvoke(del, "three")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(delaySecs * 1000)

End Sub

Delegate Sub foo(theText As String)

Private Sub updLabel(theText As Object)
    Label1.Text = DirectCast(theText, String)
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually this is what i have done, in a slightly modified way

Answer (score 1):

an inline solution, no multi-threading, no timers.

```
    Sub delay(ByVal delay_ms As Integer)
        Dim tspan As New TimeSpan
        Dim tstart = Now
        While tspan.TotalMilliseconds < delay_ms
            tspan = Now - tstart
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = "Hello"
        delay(100) 'leaks 572 ns every 10 ms
        Label1.Text = "Salut"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have each label update in a separate event and let it refresh the UI.
Create a timer that will call your event handler and in it update a different label every time

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
label.text = "intializing..."
Application.DoEvents
sleep(5000)
label1.text = "connectinh..."
Application.DoEvents
sleep(5000)
label2.text = "connected..."
Application.DoEvents
sleep(5000)
```

Application.DoEvents tells the OS process underlying work, such as updating the text value.

Answer (score 0):

```
label.text = "intializing..."
label.Refresh
sleep(5000)
label1.text = "connectinh..."
label1.Refresh
sleep(5000)
label2.text = "connected..."
label2.Refresh
sleep(5000)
```

I think this should work more properly than DoEvents!